# Show manual while in insert mode for the function I am in

Tags: neovim

While I am writing flutter I need to check the manual for the widget I am writing.
What I do is I position the cursor over the widget and press a keymap that runs

```
:lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()
```

What I would like is to achieve the same behaviour but while I am not having the cursor at the widget name, but wherever I am inside of that widget.
This is not specific request for flutter as the same behaviour would be helpful for any other language, just in flutter I do this many times since I don't really remember the widgets parameters.

I am able to create a keymap in insert mode to call the same but the problem is that the cursor is not at that position, and it should stay, but this way nothing is shown.

```
AppBar(
  elevation: 0, 
  | <the cursor is here for example>
)    

my keymap: imap <C-m> <Cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()<CR>
```

I would like to have this behaviour having the cursor where it is | and check the manual of *AppBar*

Comment: sounds like you;ll have to write some event handling and treesitter magic